# WPF DataGrid columns keep expanding, window frozen

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a weird problem which you guys might solve quickly :-)

In page there is a WPF DataGrid with some columns, I want column widths to resize dynamically when user resizes window, so it's a stretching effect.

When I set column like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Column A" Binding="{Binding ColumnA}" Width="*"/>
```

And run my app, window is frozen and columns keep expanding, like animation...
So how do I keep my columns in place and resize only when user resizes the window.

Sorry for the messy WPF, its experimentation code.

```
<Page x:Class="SharepointUploader.Pages.FieldMapping"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SharepointUploader.Pages"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="FieldMapping" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:DGRows x:Key="dgRows" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsRows" Source="{StaticResource dgRows}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="NotesForm"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsRows}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="700"/>
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

            <!--No row highlighting on selection-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgFields" Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="White" Foreground="White" Width="Auto">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <DockPanel Background="LightGray">
                                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=Form {0}}"/>
                                                    </DockPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <Expander.Content>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                </Expander.Content>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="10" CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column A" Binding="{Binding ColumnA}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column B" Binding="{Binding ColumnB}" Width="Auto" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column C" Binding="{Binding ColumnC}" Width="Auto " />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column D" Binding="{Binding ColumnD}" Width="Auto" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: explain this a bit more please ? "And run my app, window is frozen and columns keep expanding, like animation... "

Comment: There is some problem with your DataGrid GroupStyle. If you remove it, the column widths work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are placing your data grid in a Grid with no column width defined, you are infact giving infinite space to your DataGrid width wise, save would be to add a column definition to your container grid and then set your columns as "*" or "Auto"

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="Your_Max_Limit_To_Width"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Also, be sure that you need 3 columns as Auto and one as *, auto tells a column to take as much as you need from available, so if first column wants to fill up all space you will not see other columns, better would be just to give a * to all or even better remove width definitions completely.